# Difficulty using an awkward object in JS/d3

Tags: javascript, object, d3.js

I'm coding my first big JS/D3 project. I'm building a force graph that is built by the user. I'm working on a delete function, I've got it so that the nodes are deleted easily but deleting the links is being problematic.

The object for the links looks exactly like this:

```
 [{
    "source": {
            "id": "nodes0",
            "index": 0,
            "weight": 2,
            "x": 484.6237159615924,
            "y": 172.0976162005327,
            "px": 483.41969603283303,
            "py": 192.38351544975217
     },
        "target": {
            "id": "nodes1",
            "index": 0,
            "weight": 1,
            "x": 477.827442490912,
            "y": 286.60419627736496,
            "px": 477.8270286469411,
            "py": 286.61116889934317
        }
    }]
```

Now, I can delete the link perfectly with the following method if it is the source of the link but it doesn't work if it is target.

```
links.forEach(function(element, index, array){
    if(element.source.id=="nodes"+[i]||element.target.id=="nodes"+[i]){
      links.splice(index, 1) 
    }
```

can anyone see what is wrong with my code? I'm really stumped thanks so much for your help.